# clear div not functioning in IE and chrome

Tags: html, css

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/opmaster/8gVqy/) Jsfiddle, i'm trying to creat 2 input fields like so:

label (new line)

input (new line)

label2 (new line)

input2 (new line)

The email label ignores the clear both in IE and chrome.

Comment: class clear is not mentioned in the jsfiddle

Comment: If you're trying to do that why are you using floats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the formula for this pattern here: http://pea.rs/forms/top-labels

You can also Try adding :

```
display:block;
clear:both;
```

Answer (score 0):

**First point** - You had not specified any property for `.clear`.

**Second** Try the following one

```
<label for="Email" style="padding-top:10px">E-mail:</label>
```

This will work.

Here is some idea abot [Clear](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)

Comment: thanks for the reply. This will cause different behavior in FF and IE for example